# Common reasons why Maven doesn't replace properties in resources

Tags: java, spring, maven, properties

I have a general and a specific question.

Generally does anyone know of common mistakes made while including custom property file paths  in a pom.xml ?

Specifically I have:

```
<properties>
    <aProperty>false</aProperty>
</properties>
.................
<resources>
    <resource>
        <directory>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring</directory>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
        <includes>
            <include>**/*.xml</include>
        </includes>
    </resource>
</resources>
```

and a file `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring/application-security.xml` containing:

```
<beans:bean id="aBean" class="java.lang.Boolean" factory-method="valueOf">
   <beans:constructor-arg index="0" type="java.lang.String" value="${aProperty}"/>
</beans:bean>
```

So I obviously want my property replaced, but instead I get the placehodler in the resulting file.

What am I missing ?

Comment: Those aren't related... Maven placeholders != spring placeholders. So no you don't want maven to replace those you want spring to replace those at startup of your application.

Comment: Not really. They're not related yes, but I do want maven to replace those in this case. I don't have a choice there and I want to check a maven property on build not on deploy. If can propose a better way to do that it would be great.

Comment: Why do you want maven to do it instead of specifying it as a spring placeholder?

Comment: because I want to use a Maven property in there. Not a property from a property file. I could externalize all my Maven properties to a file, but this is too much work for the current change.

Comment: I wouldn't recommmend using maven for this, as you would now have to rebuild your binaries for each and every environment. For me that menas retesting everything as it are other artifacts. With a properties file you don't have this (and it is merely a copy/paste action imho). I'm not sure if maven detects the placeholders between quotes and I guess they are just copied instead of processed with `<resources />`.